# Apache Tomcat server isn't working when running Dynamic Web Application in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, tomcat, http-status-code-404

I want to add server to Eclipse which is Apache Tomcat 7.0 for running my web application but every time it is giving Error 404. I have tried all the solutions given on stack overflows other posts I will tell you what procedure I have followed:

1. I have downloaded windows installer for Apache tomcat and installed it.
2. I Placed a JAVA_HOME environment variable whose path is to the installed JDK.
3. Then in Eclipse: Window -> Preferences -> Server -> Add, I have added that server by giving the path up-to Apache bin folder.
4. Then I checked the build path of my project.

Firstly, it's giving the error that port no. is already in use, so I changed the port no. Secondly, it is giving Apache tomcat is already started. So I stopped it manually and started from Eclipse.

**The URL is *proper*, I have checked it. And I have also given the URL manually. I have also created `index.jsp`**

Now when I am running that project it is giving Error 404 . Requested file not found.

Comment: Check if URL is proper ??

Comment: mmm... are you already using a servlet to process data?

Comment: @MarceloTataje No  I have only a project which exists in eclipse which have only one servlet which I am trying to run

Comment: ok, but if you have a servlet that you want to run, you must ensure it is registered in the web.xml if you're working with an old release of tomcat, if you're using annotations, you must also check if you're usng the annotations appropiately.

Comment: @MarceloTataje But I have checked web.xml also Ther is entry for that servlet in it

Comment: maybe you can put some piece of code of your web.xml if it is okay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you look at your "web.xml" file? Look if the page you use as a welcome file exists, is there a index.jsp or index.html in your WebContent folder? ensure all the resources you´re pointing to, exist. As well, I strongly recommend you to use tomcat as a jar and not install it as a service on Windows, it is better. Also check the console of tomcat, there should be some red lines pointing to the issue that could be happening this behavior. Best regards.

Comment: I have created the index.jsp page....

Answer (score 1):

error 404 implies that the tomcat server is up and running. your problem is with whatever you are trying to 'serve'

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that your app is deployed properly.

- Check if there is any error in any of logs.
- Check if you typed in the right URL

Comment: Logs will be placed in catalina.log / any other log in APACHE_HOME/log folder

Comment: The url is Proper I have checked. And I have also given the url manually.

Comment: check the log files for any error

Answer (score 1):

Page not found or error 404 tells that there's no page at address url you trying to enter the browser. You need to check that server has configured properly to serve your application.

Answer (score 0):

just double click on --  1>Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost.server .....
..
then at ---------------  2> Server Location ......
..
select second option --  3> Use Tomcat Installation ....
..
and start the server again ... :)